# Characters that are not visible when printed

Tags: python, ascii, file-writing, non-printable

I was using an ascii code table the other day and noticed that some "unprintable" characters exist. These characters include "Null", "Start of Header", and others like them.
I tested these characters myself by attempting to print "Null" to the console like this:

```
print ("Hello" + chr(0))
```

The word Hello was output as well as a little white box with the letters "NUL". I was expecting there to be no output at all for the Null character - I thought the output would simply be "Hello".

Is this output unique to Python? If the output is written to a file is no character written? Also, if `"Hello + chr(0)"` is written somewhere and then read in by another program, will the program recognize the "Null" or will it be read as if nothing is there? Basically, is anything hidden, does anything disappear, and what is visible?

Thank you!

Comment: Where are you printing it too ? Console? IDE? Terminal?

Comment: The console. Sorry, I'll edit and specify that.

Comment: I can't recreate your issue can you provide more information ? Tested on Window's Command prompt, Python's default Shell, Linux's terminal.

Comment: `print("hello\x00")` is the same as `print("hello"+chr(0))` .. just fyi

Comment: So, it's not really an issue. I'm more just curious about unprintable characters. I'm just trying to figure out what happens when you print an unprintable character to different platforms, both visually and code-wise. I assumed that if a string contained the Null character it would simply just not show the character when printed. For example, that print("hello"+chr(0)) would output as "hello" visually, yet be stored as "hello\x00" (or whatever haha). But, when I tested it in the python console that was not the case. And that's where my questions come from:

Comment: Is the way that the string was printed in the console unique to Python? And, if the string is written to a file and then eventually read in by another program, how would the program read the string? For example, if "hello\x00" is written to a file, would the string read in as "hello\x00" or just "hello"?

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: What will happen will depend on the platform doing the printing and how the output is being displayed.  Some will show small icons, some will cause the display to do things (like CR, LF, FF, Tab, etc) and some displays will just quietly ignore it, some will just show little boxes, etc.  I doubt that Pyhton has a unique behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a function of your console display settings.  Python simply sends the given ASCII codes to your console, which it sees as Just Another Output Device, pretty much the same as writing to a file.  How to display each character is up to the console's input manager.  For instance, note how some applications will translate :-) into a single-character smiley face icon?  That's done in the display application on the other end.

You could demonstrate this by writing an equivalent output program in another language -- see how it handles the NUL character the same way.

My personal favourite is a timed string of ASCII 007 characters.  That sounds the terminal bell (usually a small "beep" these days).

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the answer! That's very interesting.

Comment: You're quite welcome.  Back when I majored in computer science, many of us had to implement a simple terminal driver or two.  The world is much nicer to deal with these days.